# MySQL - Cannot convert time format to seconds

Tags: php, mysql

I am tring to convert time format like 12:00:00 to seconds by using MySQL function. I got message say **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':00:00**. What can I do? Is there format cannot be converted? Please check my code

This works

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(2014-02-21 12:00:00,2014-02-21 13:00:00)) AS TimeInSecs 
FROM Tbl_Time
```

This not working

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(12:00:00,13:00:00)) AS TimeInSecs 
FROM Tbl_Time
```

Comment: Time is considered as a String so you need single qoutes as `TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('12:00:00','13:00:00'))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put single quotes `'` with date and time

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('12:00:00','13:00:00'));

SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2014-02-21 12:00:00','2014-02-21 13:00:00')) AS TimeInSecs ;
```

> TIMEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a time value. expr1 and
>   expr2 are time or date-and-time expressions, but both must be of the
>   same type.

[**Have a look how TIMEDIFF works.**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Answer (score 2):

Try this with  `'` single quotes

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2014-02-21 12:00:00','2014-02-21 13:00:00')) AS TimeInSecs ;
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('12:00:00','13:00:00'));
```

[TIMEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)